# why isn't this python regex statement returning my viewstate information?

Tags: python, regex

```
def ExtractViewState(string):
    m = re.match("__viewstate[^>]+value=\"\(\?<Value>[^\"]*\)", string, re.IGNORECASE)
    return m.group(0)
```

I think I'm missing something, but it m keeps returning None. Blagh.

UPDATE:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="5vzj+3s4pEHFJUQoOJbZicZdf+k2bi0uiXeIxMNTxjocu0FLzTXEI8pEcQy/V4r1vtIP6G/E0/j0C5TwvhaWdW1wJVGwGKfO26gvQk9O0zsxy5NBpx+PlfL5h7nlnAp+GmAIwdjLWxRFFbhxaOfH+yZQKfkzshBvE7xogxrTnrrlF22BiENHdWHuMqeGYb4AUfvbbJ2psQOwTTOF6meAjszLtaAxBVTgun4gVsGOKUDqasgzyYn7AsxsJ4rJ3S/64YU2sUwAsvCD1d0X3Q8bGiwriRU/pAo31xn4SfhP8dk22QbhFbVpvIwl3WGTxohL" />
```

should just return the text between in the value attribute:

"5vzj+3s4pEHFJUQoOJbZicZdf+k2bi0uiXeIxMNTxjocu0FLzTXEI8pEcQy/V4r1vtIP6G/E0/j0C5TwvhaWdW1wJVGwGKfO26gvQk9O0zsxy5NBpx+PlfL5h7nlnAp+GmAIwdjLWxRFFbhxaOfH+yZQKfkzshBvE7xogxrTnrrlF22BiENHdWHuMqeGYb4AUfvbbJ2psQOwTTOF6meAjszLtaAxBVTgun4gVsGOKUDqasgzyYn7AsxsJ4rJ3S/64YU2sUwAsvCD1d0X3Q8bGiwriRU/pAo31xn4SfhP8dk22QbhFbVpvIwl3WGTxohL"

Comment: Can you add a string on which you want to match. Without an example, it's impossible to answer.

Comment: Don't use regexes for HTML! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Have you debugged that the value of "string" is what you expect?  Is it the input tag as shown?

Comment: this is the only html parsing i am using in the whole program. I don't think it warrants importing another whole library to do this one thing... thoughts?

Comment: There's nothing terribly awful about using regular expressions to parse *a single self-contained HTML tag* as opposed to an actual structured piece of HTML with things nested inside other things. But you really, really should read the link user470379 provided anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems.

1. You need `re.search`, not `re.match`.
2. You need `(?P<...>)`, not just `(?<...>)`.
3. You have more backslashes than you need.

   `re.search("__viewstate[^>]+value=\"(?P<Value>[^\"]*)", s, re.IGNORECASE)`

works for me.

Comment: `[^>]+` doesn't greedily match "value="...?

Comment: @user470379: That's only a problem if the greedy group can eat other matches, ie `re.findall("a.+a", "aba aca")` has *one* match instead of two. Here the `[^>]` prevents that because a match has to end with the tag.

Comment: And if you use a raw string, you don't need _any_ backslashes: `r'__viewstate[^>]+value="(?P<Value>[^"]*)"'`. We almost always want raw strings for Python regexes. Also, you're capture is `m.group('Value')`

Comment: I was thinking `pattern = 'VIEWSTATE"[ ]+value="([^"]+)'` but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues:

```
import re
def ExtractViewState(string):
    # re.match looks only at the **beginning** of the string
    # dont escape the `( .. )` those capture the group
    m = re.search("__viewstate[^>]+value=\"([^\"]*)", string, re.IGNORECASE)
    # group(0) is the whole match, you want the 1st capture group
    return m.group(1)
```